# Inverted colors on opening PDF in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, pdf, color-profile

When opening [this PDF](http://dta.nl/temp/parrot%20flashgenCMYK.pdf) in Photoshop(CS3) all colors are automatically inverted.
How can I change this behaviour? The file has correct colors when opening it with Adobe Acrobat.

The file is generated by ImageMagick 6.5.6-8 2009-10-20 Q16 Open MP.

Opening a 'regular' PDF file in Photoshop does not give me any problems.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that ImageMagick is not properly embedding the color profile when generating the PDF. This is why Photoshop strips it, and turns it to negative.

Perhaps the reason why Adobe Acrobat shows it correctly is because it automatically fixes bad color profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually the JPEG compression of imageMagick used during the conversion process. Changing the compression to Zip fixes this issue.

Comment: is this because the document is CMYK, therefore a poorly supported CMYK jpeg?

Answer (score 1):

If it is only 1 layer, you can try to press ctrl + I (means invert colors). Now if it really is inverted it will show your normal colors. If not, then the colors are not inverted :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is also a low quality file, when you copy it into PS. It is correct that it is due to the compression, sometimes LZW compression. If you have a PDF file of unknown origin and are trying to edit one of the pictures in it, in Acrobat Professional you can go to Export, image, then PNG. This removes all problematic compressions, and you should be able to open them easily in PS.